# Moved Mongo Database to Different Drive: Unable to acquire lock for lockfilepath

Tags: mongodb, unix, database

I am in the process of moving my mongo data to a different drive. All of the data I want to move is stored in /data/db and I am moving it to a NAS (Network attached storage).

First step:

```
mongodump -d mydb -c mycollection -o nas/mongo-temp
```

This created a file tree in mongo-temp/ like so:

```
dump
`-- mydb
    `-- mycollection.bson

1 directory, 1 file
```

I then stopped the mongod service and created a new /data/db directory:

```
/etc/init.d/mongod stop
mkdir mongo-temp/data/db
```

...and changed the dbpath line in /etc/mongodb.conf

```
dbpath=.../mongo-temp/data/db
```

I successfully restarted the mongo server using `/etc/init.d/mongod start`.

When I try to connect:

```
mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.4
Thu May  3 09:53:23 *** warning: spider monkey build without utf8 support.  consider rebuilding with utf8 support
connecting to: test
Thu May  3 09:53:24 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 (anon):1154
exception: connect failed
```

I've tried to start mongod with the command `mongod --dbpath .../mongo-temp/data/db` but I get an error that says:

```
Thu May  3 09:57:26 exception in initAndListen std::exception: Unable to acquire lock for lockfilepath: /home/dlpstats/nas-mnt/mongo-temp/data/db/mongod.lock
```

Removing the lockfile doesn't help. If I run the mongod command without --dbpath, the server starts fine and I am able to make queries on my old database.

Answer (score 2):

First, you mentioned that you used mongodump to populate the new drive - was this just a method of backing things up or did you intend that to be the new database files?  That is not how it works - mongodump output is not the same as a database file - it needs to be re-imported with mongoresore in fact.  If you do a straight data file copy then the transfer will be seamless.

Then, as well as the permissions suggested by Wes in his answer, a few more things to check:

1. That you have shut down the old server successfully and completely - it's possible it's mis-reported error and you are getting it because it is trying to grab a port that is already open
2. You are using version 1.6.4 according to the mongo shell output, my guess is that you installed from the Ubuntu repo for 11.04 or similar, that is not a good option - 1.6 is very old at this point.  Use the 10gen repos (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages) or download the binaries and get a more recent version

Last but not least, when you start the mongod manually, make sure all the arguments are the same, like the port.  When you connect via the mongo shell, specify the port you started the mongod on - don't rely on defaults when running into issues like this, be explicit.

Comment: dump is just a backup method. I'm aware of restore and intend to use it once I get the server working. I will check on 1 and 2. Thanks

Comment: I'm on CentOS. I followed the steps at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CentOS+and+Fedora+Packages to install mongo. Is there a newer repository source for centos?

Comment: No, that is the correct source, but you seem to be running a very old version - perhaps you installed mongodb (which would hit your default repo) and not mongo-10gen etc. which will get you 2.0.4 at present, not 1.6.4

Comment: I've been tinkering since updating and still nothing. I believe the NAS may have something to do with it. I'm able to create a local directory as a database source for MongoDB just fine. But when I mount the nas, and use that directory, the unable to acquire lockfile error comes up.

Comment: what filesystem is the NAS using?  If it is Windows/MAC formatted I wonder if that could be the cause of your issues....

Comment: It's NFS...according to [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/NFS) page, that could be an issue.

Comment: Yep, NFS can cause issues, but generally they are performance issues, not problems simply starting up.  The lock error really does sound like permissions.  Perhaps try a standalone startup on that volume with no data files to test if it works at all - just see if you can start mongod with a dbpath on that volume and on a random port, see if it still errors.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem and issuing following command solved my problem:

```
rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

And then restart the `mongod`.

**But** I'm not sure is it a good solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions for the directory and parent directories of mongo-temp. Presumably it's running as the mongodb user?

You need execute permissions on the directory (and parent directories) in order to create files there. Execute permissions on a directory allow you to list the files there, which is needed to be able to open the file for writing.

Comment: I've tried various permissions including what you have above. Same result.

Comment: Set a shell in the mongodb user in /etc/passwd, and then switch to that user and try going to that folder and creating a file. If you can create a file, then it's not a permissions issue. I have a strong feeling it is, though.

Comment: Still no dice. It's able to create the lockfile but can't "acquire a lock".

Comment: Can you open the file, put something in it, and save it? (as mongodb user)

Comment: Yes, I was able to change the file as mongodb.

Comment: And mongodb owns the lock file? If so, I guess I'm out of suggestions as far as permissions go.